# How to use border-radius in safari

Tags: css, safari

http://show.bbflame.ru/border/
How to make parent(#div1) hide child's corners
Child dont overflow parents

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to overflow the borders. The closest you can get is adding a `border-radius` to the second element, which is just enough to not exceed the border.

```
#div1{
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#div2 {
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jK7TP/

Comment: I cant use border-radius for child

Comment: I cant use border-radius for child 
I wanna move it by javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
   overflow: hidden !important; /*to make sure it will work always*/
}
```

should hide any overflowing object inside #div1 if javascript moves the child inside #div1 you have a chance it won't work as it should, try using a mask or give the css properties by javascript so the properties are assigned at the same time.